# Proving $\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^2 + n^2} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi a |n|}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that:

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^2 + n^2} = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi a |n|}$$

whenever $a > 0$. I think need to use this to show that the sum equals $\coth{\pi a}$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

It clearly looks like I have to use the Poisson summation formula, but I can't seem to get very far with this...

For $f \in \mathbb{R}$, I have that:

$$\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx, \xi \in \mathbb{R}$$

The Poisson summation formula states that if $f \in \mathscr{F}$, then:

$$\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(n)$$

$$
\sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}f(n) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(n)e^{-2\pi i n^2}dn \quad \quad \quad \quad (*)
$$

I now set

$$f(n) = \frac{1}{\pi}\frac{a}{a^2 + n^2}$$

How do I begin by showing (*) from this?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to use the geometric series formula to expand $\coth \pi a$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Hello, rather than posting a new question I would ask in the comment: I've already proved the equality by Poisson summation formula but I don't know why the sum is equal to $\coth\pi a$. I searched the Laurent series of $\coth$ but it was not that helpful (at least to me). Could you explain why the sum is equal to $\coth\pi a$?

Comment: @onepotatotwopotato, The right-hand side simplifies to $$1+2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi an}=1+\frac{2e^{-2\pi a}}{1 - e^{-2\pi a}}.$$ Here, the equality follows from the geometric series formula. Now simplifying the right-hand side gives $\coth \pi a$. Also, the identity $$\coth\pi a = \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{a^2+n^2}$$ is often referred to as the 'partial fraction decomposition of $\coth\pi a$'. Certainly googling with this keyword will reveal much more about this identity. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find it easier to compute the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-2\pi a |x|}$ rather than the Fourier transform of $\dfrac{a}{\pi (a^2 + x^2)}$.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Computing the inverse Fourier transform of $\hat{f}(x) = e^{-2\pi a |n|}$ gets me $f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{2\pi i n^2}}{e^{2\pi a |n|}}dn = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i|n|}}{e^a}dn = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i|n| - a}$. How do I show that this equals $\frac{a}{\pi(a^2 + n^2)}$?

Comment: Sorry, rather: How do I show that $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{a}{\pi(a^2 + n^2)}$ = $\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i|n| - a}$?

Comment: To compute $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i x t} e^{-2 \pi a |x|}\; dx$, break it into two parts: $x > 0$ and $x < 0$.

Comment: Sorry -- I'm not seeing where the integral you typed comes into play?

Comment: The inverse Fourier transform of $\widehat{f}(x)$ is $f(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{2\pi i x t} \widehat{f}(x)\; dx$.